# Storing Location Objects on Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I want to create and store multiple location objects on Parse that will represent a users path. My current implementation has me storing location data in a csv file with lat-lon deltas, and altitude deltas, but modifying this file structure is a complicated process, and I would like to store a lot more information. 
   What I want to know is if storing these locations as a file is the best/only viable way to do it, or if it would be alright to store each location as a separate object. That way I can inspect a lot more data on each location object. Users will be regularly uploading 1000+ objects at a time, and so my concern is whether or not storing this information would take too much space and be hard to implement (I've been informed that saving a lot of objects to Parse at once can cause problems).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with creating Parse object that will contain have location with additional metadata in each field. What you can do is to create such class and then create a relationship (either pointer or [arrays](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#using-arrays) type)

This way you can store everything in the database, you will not need to deal with parsing the data on the server or the client side and you use native capabilities of parse-server. These objects can be created easily via one of the parse-server SDK's that are available for you because parse provide dedicate object for creating location objects [GeoPoint](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#geopoints)
by default parse will auto create an index in the database for each GeoPoint field in order to increase the performance. If you will do it this way you will also enjoy advanced query capabilities like: get all location which are near by me or near by specific point etc. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#geo-queries).

Comment: This is useful information, I hadn't considered keeping a geopoint on the location objects. Any insight on saving the 1000+ location objects at a time? Or what kind of issues I might face once I have several million location objects on my database?

Comment: It’s really depends on 2 things: 1. The server where your parse-server instance and running on and 2. The servers where your database is running.  Mongo is very powerful database that can handle with millions of records but you will need to know how to use it. First you need to index the relevant fields, then you need to use paging in your app